# Publish Project under name that is different to project name

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to publish a project under a different name than the project name itself. E.g. my project is called "This.Is.My.Projectname", but I want the resulting exe to be called "MyProjectname.exe".

My project is in .net5 and the project.csproj file is in SDK-Style.

Comment: How did you publish the project? If just copy the exe file, you can refer to Gökhan Aldanmaz's answer. If you are using built-in ClickOnce, you can set the name by steps: `right click project -> Publish -> start -> Folder -> ClickOnce -> Settings -> Options -> Product name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this; **Right click** on project then **properties** and **Application** part. In appplication part have assembly name. You can change this and rebuild, publish project.

Answer (score 0):

For non Visual Studio users:

The project file needs to contain `AssemblyName` e.g.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ProductName>{product_name}</ProductName>
    <AssemblyName>{name_of_exe_file_produced}</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```